# iPhone not syncing with iTunes

Tags: macos, mac, sync, itunes, iphone

In iTunes under apps tab, it list all the apps which I have in my iTunes account. When I click on the Install button of the app, button name gets changed to will install & also on the right side it shows on which page it will be installed.

When I press Apply/sync button, On top bar it shows that it is syncing in 4 steps with some progress image. These 4 steps happen so quickly & shows the status as synced.

But, the app which I wanted to install never gets synced. My iPhone is not showing the new apps which it should show after sync.

Also, It fails to restore backup which I had taken some days back.

I am using, iPhone 5 with iOS 6.0.1 Mac book pro - 10.7.5 iTunes 11.0.2(26)

I tried restaring iPhone, iTunes and the Mac. But this problem persists.

What may be happening and how do I get the apps to sync?